# Google search for my site without the dot in the name affects it's search results

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, google-ranking

I have a site, `Tanksmith.io`, which gets searched a quite a bit. The two most common queries are: `tanksmith io` and `tanksmith.io` (the latter being more correct since it contains the dot).

However the first query, `tanksmith io`, results in my page being ranked second to a site that embeds it. Whereas the second query, `tanksmith.io`, correctly results in it being ranked first. See the screenshots below.

[image: "tanksmith io"]
[image: "tanksmith.io"]

Is there possibly a way to be in first position for both queries (with and without the dot)? For example, would changing the meta tags or settings in Search Console help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not much competition then it shouldn't be hard to have the first position for both queries.

**Important:** Having said that, you can't control search engine and even if you may get position 1 for both queries it may change over time.

You may do the following:

- Have both of those phrases in your meta title and description. Talk about the same on the page.
- Try and build natural links for both of those keywords (Anchor text, point the link back to your site).
- Use social media to link the domain and talk about those phrases.
- Any additional link building should help.